# Speed up my php function

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code on my website, this function is called on every webpage, but it's slow (I did a lot of research and without this function the TTFB is about 100ms, but with this it can be even 2 seconds).

The function replaces every text in [] to a link, if a match is found in the card database. E.g.: [Inner Fire] >> and the output on the website will be:

```
<a href/card/id/name" class="quality1">Inner Fire</a>
```

It's working really great, but there are 3000 cards in the database and this is slow. Anyone can come up with a better solution to speed the process up?

Thank you in advance.

Some clarifications before the code:
sql_query:

```
function sql_query($conn, $query)
{
    return mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

Similar function with sql_fetch.

char_convert: converts utf-8 characters to HTML entity (decimal)

```
function coloredcard($text)
{
    global $conn;
    $query = "SELECT id, quality, name, collectible FROM cards";
    $result = sql_query($conn, $query);
    while ($card = sql_fetch($result))
    {
        $name_replace = strtolower(str_replace(str_split("\' "), "-", $card['name']));
        if ($card['collectible']!=0) //if collectible, replace [card_names]
        {
            $from = '['.char_convert($card['name']).']';
            $to = '<a href="/card/'.$card['id'].'/'.$name_replace.'" class="quality'.$card['quality'].'">'.$card['name'].'</a>';
            $text = str_ireplace($from, $to, $text);
        }
        elseif ($card['collectible']==0) //if not collectible replace (noncollectible card names)
        {
            $from = '('.char_convert($card['name']).')';
            $to = '<a href="/card/'.$card['id'].'/'.$name_replace.'" class="quality'.$card['quality'].'">'.$card['name'].'</a>';
            $text = str_ireplace($from, $to, $text);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Please let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to accelerate this code will be to limit the number of cards that need to be fetched from the database. I'm not going to write the code for you, but here's an outline of how that could work:

- Extract all the card names which are `[linked]` in the page, e.g. using `preg_match_all()`.
- Perform a single SQL query to load all of those cards, using `WHERE name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3', …)`.
- Loop through the result of that query and perform replacements on the HTML where appropriate.

Comment: This is probably the best answer. Looks really great.

Comment: Can you help me a little bit more? It's working great, but I have a small problem. My preg_match_all looks like this: /\[([^\]]*)\]/ , but if someone types [[Inner Fire]] it makes it [Inner Fire, instead of making it [Inner Fire]. Why it removes the two ]] from the end, but removes one from beginning? I want it remove one in all circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

Just my 2 cents:
You are not going to display 3000+ cards at the same time do you? So why not implementing an infinite loader which requests only a bunch of them (10 or so) and then asks for more as the user scrolls down?

```
 $query = "SELECT id, quality, name, collectible FROM cards LIMIT ".$offset.",10";
```

**Solution no.2:**
have another table in which you store which cards are needed on which page, something like:

```
cardpage(cardid, pageid)
```

and have a JOIN query between `card` and `cardpage` tables

Comment: Of course not. Some pages don't even have any [] used, some pages have about 5 or 10 which needs to be replaced.

Comment: "infinite loader": Never used anything like that before, but will check it out.

Comment: so have a table in which you store what cards are needed and have a JOIN query between cards and such table. please check my edit

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini I think you're misunderstanding what this code does. It's not displaying all of the cards -- it's wiki-linking them where they're referenced in the page.

Comment: @duskwuff I noticed, so that's why my second solution, just in case

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's own string functions to do the replacement stuff while fetching data, much faster than iterating in PHP:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You're making 3000 calls to `str_replace()`. You can accomplish the same result in one. See the docs for [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), notably that the first and second parameters can be arrays:

```
$search = ['things', 'to', 'search', 'for', ... ];
$replace = ['things', 'to', 'replace', 'with', ... ];
$output = str_replace($search, $replace, $input);
```

Also, cache the output so that you only have to perform the replacement once.